# Can a DriverKit System Extension match a hot pluggable device at boot time?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, iokit, kernel-extension, driverkit

I have a DriverKit extension that can match a usb audio device just fine, but if I leave the device plugged in during a reboot, the `AppleUSBAudio` kernel extension matches it instead.

Unplugging and replugging load my dext instead.

Is this to be expected? Do all System Extensions have this shortcoming? How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS 11, if one of Apple's kexts matches your device, and their driver is in the "boot" or "sys" collections (see `man kmutil`), which it normally will be, then their driver will win matching against yours, even if yours has a higher probe score.

On macOS 10.15, it should depend on whether or not their kext is in the prelinked kernel/kext cache. Third party kexts can also be included here so it's a little more democratic at least. Dexts can't be in the kextcache though.

I've filed an Apple DTS TSI about this issue and they've acknowledged it as a bug. I strongly recommend you file it as a bug as well to increase chances of it being fixed.

You should be able to work around it in a rather ugly way by [explicitly force resetting the device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iousbdeviceinterface187/1559027-usbdevicereenumerate?language=objc) from a user space daemon if your driver didn't manage to grab it. This will cause it to be re-enumerated by the USB subsystem, and for I/O Kit matching to be repeated, at which point your dext hopefully manages to win!

Comment: Yuck, but at least there's a way. Thank you! I'll try to file this. It's very lame.